# Why the SharePoint REST API will show the ExpiryDate values as "2023-05-07T23:00:00Z" while on the UI it is "08/05/2023"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a DateOnly sharepoint field named ExpiryDate as follow:-

[image]

now using the UI calendar i created a new field and i set the ExpiryDate = 08 May 2023, as follow:-

[image]

but when i get the item using the API , the ExpiryDate value will be "2023-05-07T23:00:00Z", as follow:- `https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=ID eq 759`

```
Copy
FileSystemObjectType: 0,
Id: 759,
ServerRedirectedEmbedUri: null,
ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl: "",
ContentTypeId: "0x010095BEF844045EE8499CEC73D8A275C0C500DD1025463E66EF4C8CBFBA375935734A",
Title: "07/04/2023 00:50:09",
ComplianceAssetId: null,
ExpiryDate: "2023-05-07T23:00:00Z",
LastWorkflow: "2023-03-05T21:50:09Z",
Modified: "2023-04-11T19:03:21Z",
EmailAccount: null,
ty: "2023-04-29T23:00:00Z",
ID: 759,
Created: "2023-04-06T21:50:13Z",
AuthorId: 11,
EditorId: 11,
OData__UIVersionString: "2.0",
Attachments: false,
GUID: "70e18389-e06c-4c0c-9c29-434e74085930"
```

and if i want to filter the item i need to pass filter as :-

```
/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=ExpiryDat eq '2023-05-08'
```

so why i am getting 2 different numbers for the expiry date one inside the UI and the other inside the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Because SharePoint stores date values in UTC, and converts them to whatever the regional settings (time zone) are for the site when displaying the date in the UI.

When using the REST API, you are fetching the raw date value before adjusting it to whatever time zone is required.

Comment: but if i want to filter this item i need to pass the date as 08 May and not  07 May `$filter=ExpiryDat eq '2023-05-08'`

Comment: also i added the list item using power shell such as `Add-PnPListItem -List "ListData" -Values @{"ExpiryDate"=(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"); "Title"="test" ; )}` , then the date will be saved inside the api as `ExpiryDate: "2023-04-12T00:00:00Z",` and not as `ExpiryDate: "2023-04112T23:00:00Z",`

Comment: SharePoint stores all date values in the same format and in UTC. It doesn't matter how you added it. When you fetch it from the API, you are being returned the raw date value and you need to convert it to whatever timezone/format you need (the same as what SharePoint does in the UI).